# Passing derived class to operator by reference gives error

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement derived class which comes from abstract class. I am passing derived class by reference into the function and then calling setter which is implemented in parent abstract class. This gives me memory error. I tried to illustrate the problem with simpler code but, I failed to implement it so I am trying to do it again :D

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    string name;
    string lastname;
public:
    string get_name() const { return name; };
    string get_lastname() const { return lastname; };
    string set_name(string s) { name = s; };
    string set_lastname(string s) { lastname = s; };

    virtual void get_title() = 0;

    Person() { };
    Person(string name_set, string lastname_set): name(std::move(name_set)), lastname(std::move(lastname_set)) {};
};

class Student : public Person {
private:
    vector<double > marks;
    int exam;
public:
    Student() {};
    Student(string name_set, string lastname_set):Person(name_set, lastname_set) {};
    void get_title() { cout  << "This is a student\n"; };
    void set_mark(double mark_set) { marks.push_back(mark_set); };
    void set_exam(int exam_set) { exam = exam_set; };
    double get_final() const;
    double get_final_median();
    friend bool operator > (const Student &a, const Student &b) { return a.get_final() > b.get_final(); }
    friend bool operator < (const Student &a, const Student &b) { return a.get_final() < b.get_final(); }
    friend bool operator == (const Student &a, const Student &b) { return a.get_final() == b.get_final(); }
    friend bool operator != (const Student &a, const Student &b) { return a.get_final() != b.get_final(); }

    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, Student & a) {
        int marks;
        int val;
        string st;
        std::cout << "Enter student's name: ";
        in >> st;
        // THIS PART GIVES ME AN ERROR
        a.set_name(st);
        std::cout << "And last name: ";
        in >> st;
        a.set_lastname(st);
        std::cout << "Enter marks count: ";
        in >> marks;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks; i++) {
            std::cout << "Enter mark: ";
            in >> val;
            if (val < 1 || val > 10) {
                std::cout << "Bad value";
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            a.marks.push_back(val);
        }
        std::cout << "Enter exam result: ";
        in >> val;
        if (val < 1 || val > 10) a.exam = 1;
        else a.exam = val;
        return in;
    }
};

int main() {
    Student c;
    // Error part
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is: free(): invalid size

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  Additionally, it's not complete - there's no definitions for `string`, `std::istream`, `vector<>` or `cin`, at least.

Comment: what error do you receive exactly?

Comment: Did you see [the compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae0c1f3cf72e876)?

Comment: Error I am getting is - The error I am getting is: free(): invalid size
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I also recommend turning on `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` for additional important warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I made a mistake by not returning any string value at `set_name()` function. It works on some compilers but not mine. So I changed `string set_name()` to `void set_name()` and it works. Than you all for your help!

Comment: _"It works on some compilers but not mine."_ Well, it doesn't _"work"_, it is _undefined behavior_.